# Breaking formula with long numbers into lines

Tags: formatting

So I have a formula including some long numbers, such as

```
335930276484927279713179684448448206835002480468418881341210930738473900212089315600722178371887246372987106381
```

I shall use it inline mode. As we know, LaTeX can automatically break inline formulae, but only at characters like `+`, so my long number just gets an over full hbox.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\cyc{\ensuremath{\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}}}}
\begin{document}
$(335930276484927279713179684448400599948002480468418881341210930738473900212089315600722178371887246372987106381)/37302074569722743226361185216673671881226253234397746451876987828477588889776592143236840874532233487039998236653)$
\end{document}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How or where is `\cyc` defined?

Comment: @youthdoo - MathJax rendering is intentionally disabled on this site, since primary interest here is on the TeX and LaTeX code itself.

Comment: @youthdoo ***You*** are spreading it.

Comment: @youthdoo -- Your edit has eliminated the reason that a definition of `\cyc` was requested, and now the question makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *slow*, but has the advantage you don't need to massage the expression (apart from removing `\left` and `\right`).

Between any group of four consecutive digits I add `\allowbreak` and a skip with small stretchability; between any two digits just the small stretchability. After a `)` possibly followed by a one digit exponent, `\allowbreak is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\cyc{\ensuremath{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__youthdoo_a: {\allowbreak\mspace{0mu plus 1mu}}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__youthdoo_b: {\mspace{0mu plus 1mu}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\longformula}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4}) } { \1 \c{__youthdoo_a:} \2 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([0-9])([0-9]) } { \1 \c{__youthdoo_b:} \2 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([0-9])([0-9]) } { \1 \c{__youthdoo_b:} \2 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \)(\^[0-9])? } { \0\c{allowbreak} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
$\longformula{
  (33593027648492727971317968444840059994800248046841888134121
   0930738473900212089315600722178371887246372987106381)/37302
   07456972274322636118521667367188122625323439774645187698782
   8477588889776592143236840874532233487039998236653)\cyc (c-a)^2
  (- a + \frac{73 b}{41} - \frac{32 c}{41})^{8}
 + 1/(26216145458005886280546682315846415345329784944060967701
      39379209198642899048043903972651436374524961469)
 + \cyc
   (3247787291032683363593396704757265030301310262392250089777
    755400964950131121716940315112560799942714333
   b^{4} +
   14935597499997708975672901807908209266007662371144117285530
   64062162303139916412665976626943178401469788
   c^{4}) (- a^{2} c + b^{3})^{2}+
   1/(15729687274803531768328009389507849207197870966436580620
      836275255191857394288263423835908618247149768814)\cyc
   (- a c^{2} + b^{3})^{2} \cdot
   (9077637219444070207627126379832648366875228643976851432217
    154925160941650428359503726673298227797311236
   a^{4} +
   33640372026123384267267111803613787565158779546311041973275
   62447870339103573050632122950699568384860406
   a^{3} c +
   18805484654471390423926058284835204698606630443915482929923
   483021419635327111300648671604197779613067535
   b^{4})
}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a useful code. I've always been perplexed by regexp...

Answer (score 2):

With heavy reliance on the `\seqsplit` macro... Note that I had to get rid of all `\left` and `\right` autosizing directives since LaTeX won't allow line breaks inside `\left...\right` constructs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\cyc{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}}
\usepackage{seqsplit,microtype}
\addtolength\textheight{1\baselineskip} % just to make the formula fit on one page
\setlength\medmuskip{0mu}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$
(\seqsplit{335930276484927279713179684448400599948002480468418881341210930738473900212089315600722178371887246372987106381})/(
   \seqsplit{37302074569722743226361185216673671881226253234397746451876987828477588889776592143236840874532233487039998236653})
   \cyc (c-a)^2 (- a + 73b/41 - 32c/41)^{8}
   + 1/(
   \seqsplit{2621614545800588628054668231584641534532978494406096770139379209198642899048043903972651436374524961469})
   + \cyc
   \bigl[
   \seqsplit{3247787291032683363593396704757265030301310262392250089777755400964950131121716940315112560799942714333}
   b^{4} +
   \seqsplit{1493559749999770897567290180790820926600766237114411728553064062162303139916412665976626943178401469788}
   c^{4}\bigr] 
   (- a^{2} c + b^{3})^{2}+
   1/(
   \seqsplit{15729687274803531768328009389507849207197870966436580620836275255191857394288263423835908618247149768814})
   \cyc
   (- a c^{2} + b^{3})^{2} \allowbreak\times
   \bigl[
   \seqsplit{9077637219444070207627126379832648366875228643976851432217154925160941650428359503726673298227797311236}
   a^{4} +
   \seqsplit{3364037202612338426726711180361378756515877954631104197327562447870339103573050632122950699568384860406}
   a^{3} c +
   \seqsplit{18805484654471390423926058284835204698606630443915482929923483021419635327111300648671604197779613067535}
   b^{4}\bigr] +
   41/\allowbreak(
   \seqsplit{1541125702021604563740819846772025128422288967614042545217056529270870515923315955452410851695092698081118})
   \cyc
   (- a + 73b/41 - 32c/41)^{2} \allowbreak\times
   \bigl[
   \seqsplit{828991067706635489593500025123715870603194487600421697624115664104450019438955188928251246814846059444}
   a^{7} b +
   \seqsplit{3194630001349365561681563416746853933887341399158566915491368456630849686608924948356116045177098350628}
   a b c^{6} +
   \seqsplit{2811246091581684316873069966617125845980607930084821863292127556943799988344813350383508864560076940585}
   b^{8}\bigr]+
   (115856201)(
   \seqsplit{74604149139445486452722370433347343762452506468795492903753975656955177779553184286473681749064466974079996473306})\cyc
   (- a + 73b/41 - 32c/41)^{6} \allowbreak\times
   \bigl[
   \seqsplit{94826470037738412983999862225561543528052483635838620595053124399176066119923836419858880694487982562215}
   a b^{3} +
   \seqsplit{103078744720009209861468786114727426248554349321113400088380810445184594701147855907023489933523296418922}
   a b^{2} c +
   \seqsplit{26644859854969621594886278325064797011753283566487657172270560591133276475999599701608192100941720785932}
   b^{4}\bigr] +
   (68921)(\seqsplit{74604149139445486452722370433347343762452506468795492903753975656955177779553184286473681749064466974079996473306})\cyc
   (- a + 73b/41 - 32c/41)^{4} \allowbreak\times
   \bigl[\seqsplit{285263649584146674747785456960162205302288591721897858804400634823469300152888668032103801561917148299825528}
   a^{5} b +
   \seqsplit{230665838582615265766153052657095763935020746322173136617057172813871967423286766148943736128032711821151561}
   a^{4} b^{2} +
   \seqsplit{129388294222827184315601751296457726526455758171996918654447955581563570250673884346356338069265337631357459}
   a^{2} b^{2} (a-b)^{2} +
   \seqsplit{720782970458897070253549507182406050072746797267192790803580745282442046174135996099217823519865024957882010}
   a b^{4} c +
   \seqsplit{165094086257303191232120396843946762911164522657994600238875348267682649871923344395480253551798567437787}
   a b^{3} (a-b)^{2} +
   \seqsplit{259878051623523810353371858912017696585987657969567069234313208760727019208320629939085290213408477594492820}
   a b c^{4} +
   \seqsplit{377797451438473023841482908559236091814907618899229239264163896088369917779010492459050417197096830143748540}
   b^{3} c (b - c)^{2} +
   \seqsplit{236857050020163106900940796317899857250401230052865191069086468188468333894573989935234525296070949393083863}
   b^{2} c^{4} +
   \seqsplit{237078757678781438988117308134865372204247521712482327752939482196994955213752475881211420723561967873615116}
   b^{2} c^{2} (b - c)^{2}\bigr]$

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The preceding presentation of the long formula, with its mixture of math structure and 27 [!] exceedingly long integers, is pretty much guaranteed to be utterly unreadable. You may want to think about splitting the material into two parts: First, the formula itself, using an `align*` environment that represents the long integers symbolically, as `N_1` thru `N_{27}`, and second a `longtable` that lists the long integers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,longtable,microtype,seqsplit}
\newcommand\cyc{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   N_1/N_2 \cyc &  d^{8} (c-a)^2  \\
   + 1/N_3 \cyc &  (N_4 b^{4} + N_5 c^{4}) (- a^{2} c + b^{3})^{2} \\
   + 1/N_6 \cyc &  (- a c^{2} + b^{3})^{2} (N_7 a^{4} + N_8 a^{3} c 
                   + N_9 b^{4}) \\
   + 41/N_{10} \cyc &  d^{2} ( N_{11} a^{7} b + N_{12} a b c^{6} 
                   + N_{13} b^{8}) \\
   + 115856201 N_{14} \cyc &  d^{6}(N_{15} a b^{3} + N_{16} a b^{2} c 
                   + N_{17} b^{4}) \\
   + 68921 N_{18}\smash[b]{\cyc} &  d^{4} \bigl[
              N_{19} a^{5} b + N_{20} a^{4} b^{2} 
            + N_{21} a^{2} b^{2} (a-b)^{2} \\
     &\quad + N_{22} a b^{4} c + N_{23} a b^{3} (a-b)^{2} 
            + N_{24} a b c^{4} \\
     &\quad + N_{25} b^{3} c (b - c)^{2} + N_{26} b^{2} c^{4} 
            + N_{27} b^{2} c^{2} (b - c)^{2}\bigr]
\end{align*}
where
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{$}r<{$} @{${}={}$} p{0.84\textwidth}@{}}
 d & $- a + 73b/41 - 32c/41$
\\ \addlinespace
 N_1 &
 \seqsplit{335930276484927279713179684448400599948002480468418881341210930738473900212089315600722178371887246372987106381}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_2 &
 \seqsplit{37302074569722743226361185216673671881226253234397746451876987828477588889776592143236840874532233487039998236653}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_3 &
 \seqsplit{2621614545800588628054668231584641534532978494406096770139379209198642899048043903972651436374524961469}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_4 &
 \seqsplit{3247787291032683363593396704757265030301310262392250089777755400964950131121716940315112560799942714333}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_5 &
 \seqsplit{2621614545800588628054668231584641534532978494406096770139379209198642899048043903972651436374524961469}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_6 &   
 \seqsplit{15729687274803531768328009389507849207197870966436580620836275255191857394288263423835908618247149768814}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_7 &
 \seqsplit{9077637219444070207627126379832648366875228643976851432217154925160941650428359503726673298227797311236}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_8 &
 \seqsplit{3364037202612338426726711180361378756515877954631104197327562447870339103573050632122950699568384860406}
\\ \addlinespace
  N_9 &
  \seqsplit{18805484654471390423926058284835204698606630443915482929923483021419635327111300648671604197779613067535}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_{10} &
 \seqsplit{1541125702021604563740819846772025128422288967614042545217056529270870515923315955452410851695092698081118}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_{11} &
 \seqsplit{828991067706635489593500025123715870603194487600421697624115664104450019438955188928251246814846059444}
\\ \addlinespace
 N_{12} &
 \seqsplit{3194630001349365561681563416746853933887341399158566915491368456630849686608924948356116045177098350628}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{13} &
 \seqsplit{2811246091581684316873069966617125845980607930084821863292127556943799988344813350383508864560076940585}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{14} &
 \seqsplit{74604149139445486452722370433347343762452506468795492903753975656955177779553184286473681749064466974079996473306}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{15} &
 \seqsplit{94826470037738412983999862225561543528052483635838620595053124399176066119923836419858880694487982562215}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{16} &
 \seqsplit{103078744720009209861468786114727426248554349321113400088380810445184594701147855907023489933523296418922}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{17} &
 \seqsplit{26644859854969621594886278325064797011753283566487657172270560591133276475999599701608192100941720785932}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{18} &
 \seqsplit{74604149139445486452722370433347343762452506468795492903753975656955177779553184286473681749064466974079996473306}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{19} &
 \seqsplit{285263649584146674747785456960162205302288591721897858804400634823469300152888668032103801561917148299825528}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{20} &
 \seqsplit{230665838582615265766153052657095763935020746322173136617057172813871967423286766148943736128032711821151561}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{21} &
 \seqsplit{129388294222827184315601751296457726526455758171996918654447955581563570250673884346356338069265337631357459}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{22} &
 \seqsplit{720782970458897070253549507182406050072746797267192790803580745282442046174135996099217823519865024957882010}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{23} &
 \seqsplit{165094086257303191232120396843946762911164522657994600238875348267682649871923344395480253551798567437787}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{24} &
 \seqsplit{259878051623523810353371858912017696585987657969567069234313208760727019208320629939085290213408477594492820}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{25} &
 \seqsplit{377797451438473023841482908559236091814907618899229239264163896088369917779010492459050417197096830143748540}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{26} &
 \seqsplit{236857050020163106900940796317899857250401230052865191069086468188468333894573989935234525296070949393083863}
 \\ \addlinespace
 N_{27} &
 \seqsplit{237078757678781438988117308134865372204247521712482327752939482196994955213752475881211420723561967873615116}.
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So basically this is still done by hand bit by bit right? And thanks a lot for your effort!

Comment: @youthdoo - The argument of `\seqsplit` is treated, de facto, as one big verbatim-like group. Hence the need to keep the argument of `\seqsplit` macro-free.

Comment: @youthdoo - Please see the addendum I just posted, with an attempt to serparate the formal structure of the equation from the listing of the long integers.